# How to initialize an object using a local variable

Tags: objective-c, ios

This is an extremely basic question. When I initialize an object like so...

```
UIView *view;
if (!view) {
    view = [[UIView alloc] init];
}
// Do something with view
```

I get no compiler errors, but I notice Xcode doesn't highlight `UIView` like it normally does. Am I using a bad practice to initialize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems with that code:

1. Objective-C doesn't guarantee initialization of local variables, so `view` might be 0, a pointer to something else, or a garbage value.
2. Even if Objecitve-C did initialize the variable for you, it doesn't make a lot of sense to test its value immediately after declaration.

Are you actually declaring this as an instance variable somewhere else?

As far as highlighting, which "UIView" isn't highlighted? Both? I'd try reloading the file or restarting Xcode.

To fix the two issues I named, replace that with this code:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

That raises another issue: under ARC, your newly allocated view will be deallocated when the variable goes out of scope unless you store it in an instance variable or the framework (e.g. superview) stores it somewhere else.

If you're using manual retain–release instead of ARC, you'll leak a UIView every time that method is called.

Comment: `UIView` before the if statement is not highlighted

Comment: Yea, I figured it wasn't correct. I just needed to declare it somehow to do something with the view (change a property or add to subview, etc. ). If I declare in the if statement, the I can't do anything with it after the check. What is the correct way to declare in this case?

Comment: I added a suggestion regarding highlighting.

Comment: And another regarding correct initialization of view as a local variable.

Comment: Whether this makes sense depends on what you're trying to accomplish. It likely doesn't make sense to allocate a view, use it for a second, and throw it away. But if you're adding it as a subview it won't be deallocated because the superview will hold on to it.

Comment: As a note, I also noticed that without explicit initialization in the same statement, the class keyword won't be highlighted.  If I add `= nil;` then it becomes highlighted.  Also, the new compiler (perhaps the older compilers too, I didn't check) has a warning (off by default) about uninitialized local variables being used so perhaps Apple is trying to discourage this behavior subtly by not highlighting in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't declare a local var and then check if it is nil - makes no sense.

On the other hand, if it is a property, then yes, lazy instantiantion:

```
if (!myView) {
    myView = [[UIView alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: Actually it won't always be nil, its value is undefined (as far as I know...)

Comment: So what do I do if I need to use `myView` following the check? For example, add it as a subview to another view. The method call will not recognize myView outside of nil check, correct?

Comment: If you are adding it to a subView and *don't* need to reference it again, then you don't need to check for nil - you just declare and instance it: `UIView* myView = [[UIView alloc] init];` define whatever properties and add it. If you need to reference it later then typically it is dclared as a property.

Comment: Local variables are *only initialized to nil when using ARC*.  For manual retain-release, local variables will have an effectively random value upon creation.

Comment: Good to know. (Aren't we all using ARC? ;-)

Comment: We're not :) Some of us have plenty of legacy iOS code from before ARC.

Answer (score 2):

Please, let there be some code between the first line and the second line. Because if not, you're reading the value of an uninitialized local variable, and that's an undefined behavior. Which means - it might be nonzero by pure accident.

If view is an ivar, that's different. Those are initialized to zero upon instance construction.

Comment: When compiling with ARC, object pointers are initialized to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, that's a good way to do it. If you want, you can place that if statement inside a method called view and have it return itself; this is called lazy instantiantion and is extremely common and accepted.

Comment: Only under ARC;  under non-ARC, local variables are not initialized to a known value...

Answer (score 0):

As it is, this is messy and there is not really a point to it.  Why would you check a local variable before you allocate it?  If this is altered and this is actually a method to lazy load an instance variable or property then yes this is a good way.  If this is just a normal variable then it is just noise at best and at worst you created a dangling pointer.